# Why does my Input doesn't fill the value attribute when It is written

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an email input and I'm trying to read the input value but It doen't return a value when It is filled.

`<input id="email" name="email" required="" type="email" value=" " class="form-control" />`

This is the function I'm trying to execute, saving the Value on a variable to use it later.
`var email = document.getElementById("email").value;`

I have already tried
`var email = document.getElementById("email"); console.log(email.value);`

But have no luck

Comment: the attempt is correct. But you are probably trying to read that value when it's still empty. Did you maybe set the variable anywhere in the document or are you waiting for an event to trigger? I mean where did you exactly use that statement and why did you expect it to contain the value the input had in that moment?

Comment: The variable is set when a function is called. After the input value is filled or at least that's what It looks like, when inspecting the elements on the Chrome tools there is no value, that where I get a little lost.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you decide when that action will be performed. If you put that line randomly in the file of course you have no idea but if you decide to put it in the global scope, it will be executed  once at page load and of course it will return empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this snippet, you can see how you can get the value of the input field as it changes. My suspicion is that you are trying to get the input's value before the user has filled it in (it's a common mistake)

```js
//var ch = 0;
var in1 = document.querySelector("input");
var in2 = document.querySelector("input:last-of-type");
in1.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
//  ch++;
  console.log("changed: " + in1.value);
});
in2.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  console.log("changed: " + in2.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="email" />
<input type="email" />
```